# Reading blob from function app works in local - not when published

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to access string data from a blob with a Python function app.

The function app works fine in local but doesn't return anything when published (Even though Configuration section in the portal is updated with all environment variables needed in local.settings.json)

The part `data.readall()` is what I am returning which doesn't return anything once published:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
data = blob_client.download_blob()
data.readall()
```

Any idea why I can't access the content of the blob once the app published?

Or any other idea/method that would help me debug this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it would appear that there are different behaviors according to the version of azure-storage-blob pip installed.

`data.readall()` seemed to work only for one version of the package but once upgraded to azure-storage-blob==12.14.1, the prior method doesn't work, but this one does:

`data.content_as_text()` (in local development + published function)